# ReactJS pass component as var (in ecma6)

Tags: class, reactjs, syntax, ecmascript-6, components

in one js file I have a component :

```
import React from 'react';
export default class ImageGrid extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <div>ImageGrid1</div>
  }
}
```

I want to render the above component from another component using a 'var', and I cant figure out the syntax:

```
import React from 'react';
import ImageGrid from 'components/imageGrid';
class HomePage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var div1=ImageGrid;
    return (div1); // what is the proper syntax?
  }
}
```

Comment: `return <div1 />`, but you should capitalize the variable name, i.e. `var Div1 = ImageGrid` http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/48005/

Comment: My god!!!!! all it needed was a capital letter

Comment: Yeah, because in JSX lowercase components are translated to DOM nodes and uppercase components to React elements. So you should use `var Div1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want.

```
import React from 'react';
import ImageGrid from 'components/imageGrid';

class HomePage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var SomeComponent = ImageGrid;

    return <SomeComponent />
  }
}
```

Comment: as pawel said: you should capitalize the variable name, i.e. var Div1 = ImageGrid